# Can Fortran convert "time interval + reference date" into "date" conveniently?

Tags: fortran

In other languages, there usually occurs a function to calculate the date using the reference date and time interval. For example, in `R`, if the reference date is `2019/09/01`, and the time interval is `2 days`, then the calculated date is `2019/09/03`. We can use the following date conversion function:

```
as.Date(2, origin = "2019-09-01")
# [1] "2019-09-03"
```

I was wondering if Fortran has the similar functions or packages?

Comment: Have a look at this library: https://github.com/wavebitscientific/datetime-fortran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fortran standard only provides the current date and time up to milliseconds.

```
call date_and_time ( [ date ] [ , time ] [ , zone ] [ , values ] )
```

returns the following (with default values blank or -huge(0), as appropriate, when there is no clock).

- `date` is a scalar character variable of length 8 or more. Its first 8 characters are set to the **century**, **year**, **month**, and **day** in the form **ccyymmdd**.
- `time` is a scalar character variable of length 10 or more. Its first 10 characters
  are set to the time as **hours**, **minutes**, **seconds**, and **milliseconds** in the form **hhmmss.sss**.
- `zone` is a scalar character variable of length 5 or more. Its first 5 characters are
  set to the **difference between local time and UTC** (also known as Greenwich Mean Time) in the form **Shhmm**, corresponding to sign, hours, and minutes. For example, a processor in New York in winter would return the value -0500.
- `values` is a rank-one default integer array of size at least 8 holding the sequence of
  values: the **year**, the **month** of the year, the **day of the month, the **time** difference in minutes **with respect to UTC**, the **hour of the day**, the **minutes of the hour**, the **seconds of the minute**, and the **milliseconds of the second**.

If you need anything beyond this, you will have to currently write your own functions or, as mentioned in the comments, use one of the existing ones. Among the most prominent that I know of, there is the open-srouce library **datetime-fortran** [here](https://wavebitscientific.github.io/datetime-fortran/).